# Poco::MongoDB support for MongoDB 5.0?

Tags: mongodb, poco-libraries

The MongoDB wire protocol opcodes used by the POCO MongoDB driver have been deprecated in MongoDB 5.0 (see [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-wire-protocol/#std-label-wp-request-opcodes]). I stumbled across this when attempting to use *Poco::MongoDB::InsertRequest* to insert a document into a MongoDB 5.0 "time series" collection and it failed to work. These legacy opcodes have been replaced by the OP_MSG opcode introduced in MongoDB 3.6 with the associated wire transfer request and response changes.

Is the migration of the MongoDB driver from using legacy to modern protocols somewhere in the POCO roadmap?

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question. Perhaps ask this question on one of the MongoDB forums.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This would be a POCO issue, not a MongoDB issue.  I had posted it here per https://pocoproject.org/about.html#community, but will try submitting a pocoproject/poco GitHub issue.